# How to extract the CV errors for optimal lambda using glmnet package?

Tags: r, cross-validation, glmnet, mse

I'm using the **glment** package for regression in R. I do the cross validation using `cv.fit<-cv.glmnet(x,y,...)`, and I get optimum lambda using `cvfit$lambda.min`. but I want to also get the corresponduing `MSE`(mean square error) for that lambda.
would someone help me to get it ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From `?cv.glmnet`:

```
# ...
# Value:
#
#     an object of class ‘"cv.glmnet"’ is returned, which is a list with
#     the ingredients of the cross-validation fit. 
#
# lambda: the values of ‘lambda’ used in the fits.
#
#   cvm: The mean cross-validated error - a vector of length
#       ‘length(lambda)’.
# ...
```

So in your case, the cross-validated mean squared errors are in `cv.fit$cvm` and the corresponding lambda values are in `cv.fit$lambda`.

To find the minimum MSE you can use `which` as follows:

```
i <- which(cv.fit$lambda == cv.fit$lambda.min)
mse.min <- cv.fit$cvm[i]
```

or shorter

```
mse.min <- cv.fit$cvm[cv.fit$lambda == cv.fit$lambda.min]
```

Answer (score 4):

If you running glmnet with the loss function "mse", the minimum lambda represents the minimum MSE.
Thus you could find it simply by:

`mse.min <- min(cv.fit$cvm)`